# VirtualBox Kernel panic

Tags: virtualbox, kernel-panic

I have been running VirtualBox for some weeks with no problems. Now when I start it up I get this

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill the idle task!

atkbd serio0: Spurious ACK on isa0060/serio0. Some program might be trying to 
              access hardware directly.
```

For reference the ISO is
[Slacko Puppy Linux](http://puppylinux.org/main/Download%20Latest%20Release.htm).

I tried removing and re-adding the hard disk as
[has been suggested](https://superuser.com/a/185898).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried loading Ubuntu rather than Puppy and it worked. However before booting Ubuntu also put out an error

```
SMBus base address uninitialized - upgrade BIOS or use force_addr=0xaddr
```

Looking up that error led me to a
[blog post](http://fbinotto.blogspot.com/2012/03/smbus-base-address-uninitialized.html) that suggests

> reset the VM and after selecting the language just press F6 and press enter to
>   select `acpi=off` then ESC to go back. This should do it.